# Japanese for submarine sandwich

Tags: translation, words

Does Japanese have a commonly used term for submarine sandwich/roll?

Australian English doesn't have a term AFAIK (the only places that sell such things in Australia are the Subway franchise), and I was wondering if the same was true for Japanese.

I couldn't spot it in jisho.org and the English edition of Wikipedia's article on submarine sandwiches didn't have a Japanese inter-language link. I came across "サブマリーンサンドイッチ" on Weblio but I don't know how authentic it is.

Comment: I think `サブマリン` is the usual transcription of *submarine*, not `サブマリーン`.  Corpus results suggest the former is more than 100x more common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you shouted 「サブマリンサンドイッチ」 in my neighborhood, no one except me and perhaps another person would know what you were saying.  That word would **not** be in the vocabulary of over 5% of our population.  (The 「サンドイッチ」 part, I asure you, would be understood by virtually 100% of us.)

If you want to talk about a submarine sandwich, you would probably have to describe it like:

「[大]{おお}きいアメリカンタイプのサンドイッチ」

「大きくて[長]{なが}いサンドイッチ」

「サブウェイで[売]{う}ってるような（長い）サンドイッチ」